# How to do batch processing using multi-threading in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I am using parallel foreach to add values in a blocking collection but when the blocking collection has 10 values i need to do some processing with that and then clear that blocking collection again and then again start adding value to the blocking collection.

There are two problems here

1. while i am doing some processing with that it will keep adding values to the blocking collection , i can put a lock on the list but still by the time it reaches the lock the value would have got increased.
2. If i am putting the lock that totally spoils the use of  parallel programming, i want the addition to that object to happen in that list till the time those 10 messages are processed. I can copy the lists contents and empty the list again here also the same issue i cannot copy only 10 items because the contents have already changed.

sometimes the if condition is never satisfied because before the conditon is checked the values is increased.

Is there any solution to this ?

```
public static BlockingCollection<string> failedMessages = new BlockingCollection<string>();
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var myCollection = new List<string>();
    myCollection.Add("test");
    //Consider myCollection having more than 100 items 
    Parallel.ForEach(myCollection, item =>
    {
        failedMessages.Add(item);
        if (failedMessages.Count == 10)
        {
            DoSomething();
        }
    });

}

static public void DoSomething()
{
    //dosome operation with failedMessages 
    failedMessages = new BlockingCollection<string>();
}
```

Comment: You always add new item, it make sense to preallocate and use array.

Comment: @Sinatr but again if i use array with size 10 when i am running the program it will throw  exception if i am adding 11th element.

Comment: Do you want to modify collection inside `DoSomething()`?

Comment: @Sinatr no its just i will send it to servicebus as a batch message, i will not modify the collection inside  DoSomething()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a job for DataFlow:

Example using a `BatchBlock<string>` with a batchsize of 10 and an `ActionBlock<string[]>` to consume Batches:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        // Set up DataFlow Blocks
        BatchBlock<string> batcher = new BatchBlock<string>( 10 );
        ActionBlock<string[]> consumer = 
            new ActionBlock<string[]>( 
                (msgs) => Console.WriteLine("Processed {0} messages.", msgs.Length)
            );
        // put them together
        batcher.LinkTo( consumer );
        
        // start posting
        Parallel.For( 0, 103, (i) => batcher.Post(string.Format("Test {0}",i)));
        
        // shutdown
        batcher.Complete();
        batcher.Completion.Wait();
    }
}
```

In action: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y9Ezg4

Further Reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/walkthrough-using-batchblock-and-batchedjoinblock-to-improve-efficiency

---

EDIT: As requested - if you cannot or do not want to use DataFlow, you can of course do something similar:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        FailedMessageHandler fmh = new FailedMessageHandler( new Progress<string[]>((list) => { Console.WriteLine("Handling {0} messages. [{1}]", list.Length, string.Join(",", list));}));
        Parallel.For(0,52, (i) => {fmh.Add(string.Format("Test {0,3}",i));});
        Thread.Sleep(1500); // Demo: Timeout
        var result = Parallel.For(53,107, (i) => {fmh.Add(string.Format("Test {0,3}",i));});
        while(!result.IsCompleted)
        {
            // Let Parallel.For run to end ...
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
        // Graceful shutdown:
        fmh.CompleteAdding();
        fmh.AwaitCompletion();
    }
}

public class FailedMessageHandler
{
    private BlockingCollection<string> workQueue = new BlockingCollection<string>();
    private List<string> currentBuffer = new List<string>(10);
    private IProgress<string[]> progress;
    private Thread workThread;
    
    public FailedMessageHandler( IProgress<string[]> progress )
    {
        this.progress = progress;
        workThread = new Thread(WatchDog);
        workThread.Start();
    }
    
    public void Add( string failedMessage )
    {
        if ( workQueue.IsAddingCompleted )
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Adding is completed!");
        }
        
        workQueue.Add(failedMessage);
    }
    
    private void WatchDog()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            // Demo: Include a timeout - If there are less than 10 items
            // for x amount of time, send whatever you got so far.
            CancellationTokenSource timeout = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            try{
               var failedMsg = workQueue.Take(timeout.Token);
               currentBuffer.Add(failedMsg);
               if( currentBuffer.Count >= 10 ){
                   progress.Report(currentBuffer.ToArray());
                   currentBuffer.Clear();
               }
            }
            catch(OperationCanceledException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TIMEOUT!");
                // timeout.
                if( currentBuffer.Any() ) // handle items if there are
                {
                    progress.Report(currentBuffer.ToArray());
                    currentBuffer.Clear();
                }
            }
            catch(InvalidOperationException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("COMPLETED!");
                // queue has been completed.
                if( currentBuffer.Any() ) // handle remaining items
                {
                    progress.Report(currentBuffer.ToArray());
                    currentBuffer.Clear();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("DONE!");
    }
    
    public void CompleteAdding()
    {
        workQueue.CompleteAdding();
    }
    
    public void AwaitCompletion()
    {
        if( workThread != null )
            workThread.Join();
    }
}
```

In Action: https://dotnetfiddle.net/H2Rg35

Mind, that the use of `Progress` will execute the handling on the main thread. If you pass an `Action` instead, it would execute on the `workThread`. So, tweak the example to your requirements.

This is also just to give an idea, there are a lot of variations of this, maybe using Task/Async ...

Comment: thank you so much this resolved the issue  it would be great if you can post the other solutions which you gave it in the comment section earlier. 

End of the day I posted this question for learning more the resolution and this has served both the purposes

Comment: Will do. It'll take some time, though.

Comment: @kannangokul Added non-DataFlow example.